# How can I do a CVS checkout without using the Cvs module?

Tags: perl, cvs

How to do CVS co using Perl without using [Cvs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Cvs) module ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the CVS module?

Comment: my server system wont allow me to install !

Comment: local::lib might prove useful to help you install modules in your home directory rather than requiring the permission of the system administrator.  http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?local::lib

Answer (score 6, accepted):

system :  http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html

Comment: Nope, better use a module provided by the CPAN, but you asked not to use one.

Comment: @SCNCN2010 - I usually try a CPAN search first, then think about using some form of a system command.

Answer (score 1):

While you asked not to use a module, I always recommend it.  CPAN kicks up [Cvs::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~stephenca/Cvs-Simple-0.06/lib/Cvs/Simple.pm).  You may want to consider using it as a reference if you have business case reasons for not using a module.

Comment: "I reject your reality, and substitute my own."

Comment: @jrockway - there can be good reasons to not use modules, but the OP didn't give one.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this up in [my blog](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/edburns/archive/2011/07/01/using-expect-work-around-cvs-ssh-checkout-0) but here it is in plain text.

I had to download and install expectperl and the IO::Tty perl module. This little perl script successfully does the cvs update, even with the ssh password prompting.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Expect;

chdir("/files/hudson_local/jobs/MOJARRA_1_2X_ROLLING_GLASSFISH_2_1_1/workspace");
$ENV{"CVSROOT"} = ":ext:8bit@java.net/cvs/javaserverfaces-sources~cvs-repository";

($cvs = Expect->spawn("cvs update -d -P")) || die "Couldn't spawn cvs, $!";

unless ($cvs->expect(30, "Enter passphrase for key '/files/hudson_local/.ssh/id_rsa':")) {
  die "Never got the passphrase prompt";
}

print $cvs "not the real password\r";

unless ($cvs->expect(300, "cvs update: Updating www/legal/jsf-cddl")) {
  die "Never saw update starting";
}
```